# SQL query with joins that are not used in where that return more rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, join, sql-server-2012

I'm working on a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 from an ex-employee, which goes something like this:

```
SELECT 
    t1.colx, t1.coly, t2.colz
FROM 
    table1 t1
INNER JOIN 
    table2 t2 ON t2.col2 = t1.col2
INNER JOIN 
    table3 t3 ON t3.col3 = t2.col3
INNER JOIN 
    table4 t4 ON t4.col4 = t3.col4
INNER JOIN 
    table5 t5 ON t5.col5 = t4.col5
WHERE 
    t1.col6 = 1 AND t2.col7 = 2
```

There are couple of things I can't understand about it:

1. What's the point of joining `table4` and `table5` when they're not used in the `WHERE` clause? How does it benefit the query? They're not used in `SELECT` either.
2. When I remove the last 2 joins from the query, `SELECT` returns fewer number of records. With the last 2 `JOIN`s included, it returns more records. How's that work? First `JOIN` is between `table1` and `table2`, with all other `INNER JOIN`s, if there are say 500 records common between `table1` and `table2`, how come the last two `JOIN`s cause the query to return more records?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) This forces there to be a corresponding record in table5. If the record isn't in table5, the data won't show up.

2) This is because table4 and/or table5 have more than one row that joins. This is why you are getting more records with the joins in than without.

Comment: 1) OK. 2) Does this mean some records from table1 are included more than once? If joins are returning 3 rows from table5, does it mean I'm getting the same row from Table1 thrice?

Comment: @artm yes. Add the keyword DISTINCT after the SELECT keyword to eliminate these.

Comment: I thought about DISTINCT as well but this SP actually does a SUM on a column and it calculates the total profit of the office for the given period, and testers and admin and account and all that insist that it gives the correct amount. It seemed incorrect to me too but not sure how to convince all those people that the SUM of this query is not the correct profit. They've been using this SP for a couple of years and that SUM value is used in monthly reports to the CEO and annual reports and that.

Comment: @artm Find a record that is allowing duplicates from table4/table5 and manually verify the calculation is correct for that one.

Comment: Yeah, will have to dig deeper. It returns some 7000 records so need to find a way to find the duplicates. Thanks, appreciated. PS: How come when I type "@Spe" it doesn't show your name here?

Comment: @artm no idea why the @ isn't showing my name for you. As far as finding the record, the way I normally find it is to group on an id, add a count, and add having count > 1. Finds it everytime

Comment: Cheers, you've been very helpful.